# Where are the parameters of this function?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, declaration

```
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

The return type is void* and proto_type is the name of the function? Or is this a pointer to function? Which are the parameters:

`(long int, char *b)` or this `(const char *b, unsigned short int d)`

Please, explain how this function works.

Comment: The return type is a function pointer.

Comment: Although you've already received a number of good answers, I believe that you would still gain from reading this document (I know I did...): [`Reading C Declarations: A Guide for the Mystified`](http://untroubled.org/articles/cdecls.txt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

This is a function declaration. The function name is `proto_type`, which takes two parameters of types:

- `long int`
- `char *`

and returns a pointer to a function which takes

- `const char*`
- `unsigned short int`

and returns `void*`.

Now if you use typedef, all of the above will becomes obvious:

```
typedef void* function_type(const char *b, unsigned short int d);

function_type* proto_type(long int, char *b);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

This declares `proto_type` as function taking `(long int, char *)` and returning pointer to a function taking a `(const char *, unsigned short int)` and returning a void pointer.

In other words:

```
typedef void * (*R)(const char *, unsigned short int);   // return type

R proto_type(long int, char *);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest bookmarking [www.cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org/) for the questions of this type. Beware, the page is a bit picky about what you type in (it doesn't accept parameter names at least).

Comment: thanks i did this and wrote up an answer, but you still get my up vote!

Answer (score 2):

Start with the name of the function, then evaluate that using
the usual expression syntax.  Thus:

```
proto_type                  //  proto_type 
proto_type( long, char* )   //  is a function taking long, char*
                            //  (since function call has precedence over *
*proto_type( long, char* )  //  returning a pointer
(*proto_type(...))          //  (no change, but necessary for precedence reasons)
(...)( char const*, unsigned short )
                            //  to a function taking char const*, unsigned short
*(...)(...)                 //  returning pointer
void *(...)(...)            //  to void
```

(It's a little harder in cases where you don't have the name,
like the type in a `static_cast`.)

Answer (score 2):

I will explain my process for parsing complex c-style declarations.  I hope you will find it useful.

C-style parsing can be thought of as a right-to-left parsing starting at the identifier and bounded by parenthesis.  So we start at the identifier `proto_type`

```
//       vvvvvvvvvv-------------------
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

As we can see, moving right from proto_type, we immediately see a function call and some parameters, so that's easy.  `proto_type` is a function that takes a `long int` and `char*` as parameters.

```
//                                   v
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

Here we hit the first bounding parentheses, so we have to go backwards to find the next token which is here:

```
//      v----------------------------
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

So now we know it returns a pointer to something.  Now we have to look to the right again to find out what because of the bounding parentheses again

```
//     v--------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

Since we found another function call operator, the pointer it returns must be a pointer to a function that takes a `const char*` and an `unsigned short int`.

Finally, we reached another bounding parentheses, so move back left to find the return value of that function pointer.

```
//vvvv----------------------------------------------------------------------v
void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
```

The function pointer returns a void* as the return value.

So to recap in English:  `proto_type` takes a `long int` and a `char*` as parameters and returns a pointer to a function that takes a `const char*` and `unsigned short int` as parameters and returns a `void*`.

Comment: Your explanation clarified these things. Thanks!

Comment: @user2679377 preferred way to say thanks on  SO is vote (and now you can vote-up as your repo is +15) any/all helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`proto_type` is a function, which takes two arguments, `long int` and `char *`. It returns a function pointer that takes two arguments of type  `const char *` and `unsigned short int`.

And to write this without using typedef is not very kind to the reader.

Comment: Question of habit.  The typedef won't make the variable any easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Using VS2012 on Windows 8 x64.

`proto_type` is a function that takes a `long int` (which is unnamed) and an `unsigned short int d`, and returns a function of the form `void * proto2(const char *b, unsigned short int d);`

Here's some working code:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d);
void * proto2(const char *b, unsigned short int d);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(proto_type(0, NULL)(NULL, 0) != (void*)8675309)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

void * (*proto_type(long int, char *b)) (const char *b, unsigned short int d){
    return &proto2;
}

void* proto2(const char *b, unsigned short int d){
    return (void*)8675309;
}
```

What's going on is that `main` calls `proto_type` which returns a pointer to `proto2`, which `main` immediately calls. `proto2` returns a magic pointer value that we check against in `main`.

Here's the debug output from VS2012:

`The program '[3188] test.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).`

As for "how this function works", the answer is however you want it to (assuming you're the one implementing it).

If you want another way to look at it, you want to read it inside to out for the order of which functions are called.

The lesson here is that C(++) function pointers are immensely opaque.

Answer (score 1):

I have done what @Tomek said and copied your prototype to http:www.cdel.org and then removed the parameter names from the prototype as:

```
    void * (*proto_type(long int, char *)) (const char *, unsigned short int );
```

pressed enter, and the web site returned:

```
declare proto_type as function (long int, pointer to char) returning pointer
to function (pointer to const char, unsigned short int) returning pointer
to void
```

Now, to translate this into carbon-unit speak:  proto_type is declared as a function that takes a `long int` and a pointer to a `char` as parameters, it returns a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a `const char` and an `unsigned short integer` and that function returns a `void pointer`.

Finally, a `void pointer` can be cast into a pointer to any other data type.